# Accessing multiple pages of plots

Tags: r

I am using the `plot()` function to plot the diagnostics from the `MCMCglmm` package (I don't think it's important which package I'm using as the same thing happens with other packages):

```
fit <- MCMCglmm(.....)
plot(fit)
```

This then produces a page of plots, and in the console it says `Waiting to confirm page change...` Normally when I want to save a plot (for example to put in a word processing document) I just right-click the plot and select one of the options, such as "copy as bitmap". However, when I do this with multiple pages of plots, the right-click causes the next page to display and I am only able access the final page. Is there a way to prevent this, or another way to access the intermediate pages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is important, which package you use, since usually they come with their own plot method.

E.g., `plot.lm` and some others have the parameter `which`:

```
fit<-lm(c(1,2,4,5,6)~c(3,4,5,6,7.2))
plot(fit)
plot(fit,which=1)
```

`plot.MCMCglmm` doesn't seem to have this parameter:

```
require(MCMCglmm)
data(PlodiaPO) 
model1<-MCMCglmm(PO~1, random=~FSfamily, data=PlodiaPO, verbose=FALSE)
plot(model1)
plot(model1$VCV)
plot(model1$VCV[,1])
plot(model1$VCV[,2])
plot(density(model1$VCV[,1]))
plot.default(model1$VCV[,1],type="l")
```

Comment: Thank you. You have pointed me in the right direction. In my case I have many fixed effects, so I have been able to achieve what I want by `plot(fit$Sol[,1:4])` and then `plot(fit$Sol[,5:8])` etc. Do you think this is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite trivial. You can press "Esc" key, to stay on the current plot and copy/save it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
dev.print(width=480,height=480,device=png,paste("folder/graph",i,".png",sep=""))
```